# Build linux kernel UML error

Tags: c, build, linux-kernel

I downloaded
[Linux 3.12.36](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x/linux-3.12.36.tar.xz) and followed the instructions at http://user-mode-linux.sourceforge.net/source.html.

However in the `make ARCH=um` step, I got the error

> In file included from arch/um/kernel/config.c:8:0:
>   ***/linux-3.12.36/arch/um/include/shared/init.h:129.26: error : expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' beofer '__used'
>
> #define __uml_setup_help __used __section(.uml.help.init)

Comment: Please, transform build log from image to the **text**. At least, you may type **the first** error message from the image. Then try to google that error message.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the gcc version. I used gcc5 and could not compile it. When I switched to gcc4.9, I succeeded.